# Print results remaining in the ValidationResult error list .NET

Tags: c#, .net

My code is the following one:

```
//Validate that all the attributes are well setted

ValidationContext vc = new ValidationContext(callDAO, null, null);
var resultsValidation = new List<ValidationResult>();
bool validated = Validator.TryValidateObject(callDAO, vc, resultsValidation, true);

if(validated)
{
   //Execute some code
}
else{
     notValidated++;
     var errorValidations = resultsValidation.Select(v => v.ErrorMessage);
     log.Error(string.Format("The attribute VALIDATION FAILED due to: " + errorValidations));
}
```

What I want to do is print the errors contained in "errorValidations" in my log file correctly. But when writting in the log, the following is written:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationResult,System.String]
```

**Question:** How can I display correctly the information contained in the "resultsValidation"?

**Note:** Example of the content in the "resultsValidation" when an attribut lenght that was introduced was bigger than the defined:

```
[0] {The field Id must be a string with a maximum lenght of 15.}
```

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`errorValidations` is of the type `IEnumerable<ValidationResult>`, you need a `foreach` loop to iterate through the collection to print each validation result,

```
foreach (ValidationResult result in errorValidations)
    log.Error("The attribute VALIDATION FAILED due to: " + result.ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you very much @kennyzx, it works! ^^ I would like to vote your answer but I can't due to I don't have 15 of reputation yet, sorry.